# solr autocomplete keywords from multiple fields

Tags: solr, autocomplete

I'm new to Solr and would like to implement an autocomplete feature based on two fields title and description. In addition the resultset should be further restricted by other fields such as id and category. Sample data:

```
Title: The brown fox lives in the woods
Description: The fox is found in the woods where brown leaves cover the ground. The animal's fur is brown in color and has a long tail.
```

Desired autocomplete result:

```
brown fox
brown leaves
brown color
```

Here are the relevant entries from schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>


<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="category" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="ac-terms" type="autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" />
<copyField source="title" dest="ac-terms"/> 
<copyField source="description" dest="ac-terms"/>
```

Query request:

```
http://localhost:9090/solr/select?q=(ac-terms:brown)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved using ShingleFilterFactory with the following configuration:

```
<fieldType name="autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="ac-terms" type="autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" />
<copyField source="title" dest="ac-terms"/>
<copyField source="description" dest="ac-terms"/>
```

Query request:

```
http://localhost:9090/solr/select?q=&facet=true&facet.field=ac-terms&facet.prefix=brown
```

Result:

```
brown color
brown fox
brown leaves
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: thanks for such a great example. Is there a way to give these results a weight to order them?

Answer (score 0):

What about making a field `spellcheck_text` and using the copy field feature so that the `title` and `description` are automatically destined to `spellcheck_text`?

> ...instruct Solr that you want it to duplicate any data it sees in the
>   "source" field of documents that are added to the index, in the "dest"
>   field of that document. ... The **original text** is sent from the
>   "source" field to the "dest" field, before any configured analyzers
>   for the originating or destination field are invoked.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields

Comment: Have I not done that by declaring ac-terms? What am I missing?